# Exponentially distributed random variable inquality (using memoryless property)

Tags: probability, probability-theory, exponential-distribution

This is my first post :) So given a exponentially distributed random variable $X$, how do I show that for $t,s$ positive integers and $u\in [0,s]$:
$$
P(X>t+s-u)=P(X>t)P(X>s-u)
$$
I know that I need to use the memoryless property, but I am stuck at how to do that? I am a bit confused how to get to the product.

Comment: hint $P(X>t+s-u)=e^{-\lambda (t+s-u)}=e^{-\lambda( t+(s-u))}=e^{-\lambda t}e^{-\lambda(s-u)}$

Comment: Thank you very much, great help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HINT**

Note that since $0 \le u \le s$ we have $s-u > 0$ so letting $v = s-u$ you must show that
$$
\mathbb{P}[X > t+v] = \mathbb{P}[X>t] \cdot \mathbb{P}[X > v]
$$

Consider conditioning on $X>t$. We have
$$
\mathbb{P}[X > t+v]
 = \mathbb{P}[X > t+v, X > t]
 = \mathbb{P}[X > t] \cdot \mathbb{P}[X > t+v | X > t]
$$
Can you now use the memoryless property to simplify?

Comment: It may help the reader to take $P(X>t+v) = P(X>t+v,X>t)$ as the first step.

Comment: @spalein +1, did not think of it, added it in now

Comment: Appreciate your help, got it! Thank you :)